# Resharper: Disable "Path not found" for friendly urls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I am making an ASP.NET forms project that uses friendly urls.

For example, a friendly url for the page located at "~/About.aspx" would be "~/About".

Resharper reports a "path not found" error for all links to a page that use a friendly url.  This is problematic, because the page does exist and therefore Resharper is reporting a false positive. How do I configure Resharper to know about friendly urls and thereby not report the issue when the mapped page exists?

Comment: Does [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/15/resharpers-web-path-mapping-explained/) help?

Comment: @Andrei yes - can't believe it was so obvious. All I had to do was "Set Path Mapping" to a file in my project.